# Buyng Ram EOSIO

Tags: nodeos, eosjs, eosio-code, eosio.token

Hello i want to make api for buying RAM so is there any api available or any library please let me know but im already using eosjs ,eos-api of nodejs please let me know in comment thank you

Answer (score 1):

You can use eosjs to solve this.

According to the documentation here: https://developers.eos.io/manuals/eosjs/latest/how-to-guides/how-to-stake

You can stake for resources. The example below is staking for NET and CPU for the user "mynewaccount" in the name of "useraaaaaaaa". I assume if you provide the "stake_ram_quantity" it will work.

```
(async () => {
await api.transact({
    actions: [{
      account: 'eosio',
      name: 'delegatebw',
      authorization: [{
        actor: 'useraaaaaaaa',
        permission: 'active',
      }],
      data: {
        from: 'useraaaaaaaa',
        receiver: 'mynewaccount',
        stake_net_quantity: '1.0000 SYS',
        stake_cpu_quantity: '1.0000 SYS',
        transfer: false,
      }
    }]
  }, {
    blocksBehind: 3,
    expireSeconds: 30,
  });
})();
```

So you really only need to push eosio::delegatebw action which you can check out on bloks.io for more information.

Comment: i tried this but it only increases Cpu ,net only not showing ram iincreased

Comment: did you delete the "stake_net_quantity" and "stake_cpu_quantity" variables from the "data" object and use only "stake_ram_quantity" instead? I mean something like this:data: {
        from: 'useraaaaaaaa',
        receiver: 'mynewaccount',
        stake_ram_quantity: '1.0000 SYS',
        transfer: false,
      }

Comment: got it thanks its solved